# How to bypass the Local Development Server for Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

The Local Development Server for Google App Engine is great for testing - but we would also like to test against our databases in Google's cloud as well.

We tried setting the [--host option for the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command) in the hopes that we could bypass localhost - but it throws an error that it cannot bind our services on Google's x.appspot.com (i.e. where x is our project.)

How does one bypass the local development server so our Python App Engine app connects to Google Cloud SQL and Cloud DataStore *in* in the Cloud rather than the local versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cloud Datastore**

There is now a client [google-cloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) that allows you to directly access the datastore assuming the client has the correct credentials.

The easiest way to try this out is in a Cloud Shell -

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud
$ python
>>> from google.cloud import datastore
>>> client = datastore.Client(project='YOUR-PROJECT-ID')
>>> query = client.query(kind='YOUR-ENTITY')
>>> for result in query.fetch():
>>>   print(result)
```

You can find more information on authentication in the docs.

**Cloud SQL**

You can connect to a Cloud SQL instance through the following ways:

- IP address (with and without SSL)
- Cloud SQL Proxy (binary or Docker image)
- MySQL Socket Library (Java only)
- Go Proxy Library (Go only)
- Cloud Shell (uses temporary IP whitelisting)

I'd recommend connecting through the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy).

**Alternative for testing**

I believe it's also worth asking yourself what you are trying to test and whether you can avoid connecting to the prod DB directly. I'd recommend setting up a staging environment instead where you can import a subset of prod data on a regular basis through a script, properly anonymizing sensitive user data and running your E2E tests against that environment to avoid any potential negative side effects on your production system.